# Global object loaded through external CDN used in callback not available at runtime

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dom, bing-maps, cdn

I am using BingMaps Api. I use JavaScript to append a script tag into the DOM which loads the CDN. I then declare a global function to use as the callback when the CDN is loaded as the documentation says.

However, when the callback is run, I keep getting "TypeError: Microsoft.Map is not a constructor".

When I type "Microsoft" into the console, I see that it's there. This problem does not happen when I put the script directly into the HTML. Why is this?

The code can be viewed and executed in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/1z4o7km3ml

```js
// insert script tag into DOM

const bingScript = document.createElement("script");
bingScript.type = "text/javascript";
bingScript.src =
  "https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=onLoadApi";
document.head.appendChild(bingScript);

//insert div element into DOM
const mapDiv = document.createElement("div");
mapDiv.id = "bingMap";
mapDiv.setAttribute("style", 
"position:relative;width:600px;height:400px;");
document.body.appendChild(mapDiv);

window.onLoadApi = () => {
  try {
    const map = new 
window.Microsoft.Map(document.getElementById("bingMap"), {
      credentials:
        <API KEY>
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
};
```

Comment: As you guessed with your tag names, script elements that are dynamically appended to the DOM are loaded and evaluated asynchronously. Apparently your `onLoadApi` is called before it's ready.

Comment: @Bergi But the only thing that calls onLoadApi is the bingmap script `"https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=onLoadApi...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, everything is fine with your example except the line where map object is instantiated:

```
const map = new window.Microsoft.Map(document.getElementById("bingMap"), {
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  credentials: API_KEY
});
```

There is a typo here, [`Map` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-api/map-class) is declared under [`Microsoft.Maps` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-api/?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fbingmaps%2Fv8-web-control%2FTOC.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2FBingMaps%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json), but **not** under `Microsoft` namespace as in your example, that's the reason why the specified error occurs:

> TypeError: window.Microsoft.Map is not a constructor

Comment: Oh my god. -_-"

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why the previous code didn't work. Even after setting a timeout for five seconds before running the createMap() function, Microsoft object was still not available. If someone can shed insight it will still be greatly appreciated. But the solution is to wrap the callback in a promise.

```js
import "./styles.css";
let initializedPromise = null
//insert div element into DOM
const mapDiv = document.createElement("div");
mapDiv.id = "bingMap";
mapDiv.setAttribute("style", "position:relative;width:600px;height:400px;");
document.body.appendChild(mapDiv);

const insertBingScriptIntoDom = () => {
  const bingScript = document.createElement("script");
  bingScript.type = "text/javascript";
  bingScript.src =
    "https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=onLoadApi;
  document.body.appendChild(bingScript);
};

const initApi = () => {
  if (!initializedPromise) {
    initializedPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      window.onLoadApi = () => {
        resolve()
      }
    })
    insertBingScriptIntoDom()
  }
  return initializedPromise
}

const createMap = async () => {
  await initApi()
  new window.Microsoft.Maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    credentials: <API KEY>,
    center: window.Microsoft.Maps.Location(41.6, 2.9)
  })
}

createMap()
```